# Как в хеш-таблице указать несколько значений к одному ключу? C#

Tags: c#, графы

Читаю книгу ***"Грокаем Алгоритмы"*** - *Адитьи Бхаргавы*.

Там такой момент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Попытка:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: Как в хеш-таблице указать несколько значений к одному ключу на С#? Целесообразно ли изображать Граф через Хеш-Таблицу в дальнейшем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используйте в качестве значения коллекцию элементов, например

```
table["key"] = new []{"val1", "val2", "val3"};
```

По поводу графов - если вам нужен константный доступ к ребрам узла по ключу (и массив - не ваш вариант), то имеет смысл пользоваться таблицей или лучше словариком (`Dictionary<>`), если такой доступ не нужен - то нет смысла использовать таблицу.

Comment: Можно же в качестве значений, кидать список?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer можно и список