# Как вывести хэш таблицу имеющую один ключ и несколько значений?

Tags: c#

После [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875049/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83-c) вопроса, сразу возник следующий. Если в хеш-таблице ключ имеет несколько значений, то как их все сразу вывести?

***Мой код:***

```
        Hashtable graph = new Hashtable();

        graph["my"] = new[] { "alice", "bob", "claire" };
        graph["bob"] = new[] { "anuj", "peggy" };
        graph["alice"] = new[] { "peggy" };

        foreach (var element in graph.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element + " friends is " + graph[element]);
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(element + " friends is " + string.Join(",",  graph[element] as string[]));
```

или

```
Console.WriteLine($"{element} friends is {string.Join(",", graph[element] as string[])}");
```

Но вообще вместо `Hastable` лучше использовать типизированное множество, например, `Dictionary<string, string[]>`

Comment: Что делает string.Join(",",  graph[element] as string[]) в целом? + почему Dictionary лучше Хештейбла?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tk0xe5h0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) принимает в параметрах разделитель и набор элементов, а на выходе формирует строку из этого набора элементов и разделителя между ними.

Comment: [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) лучше потому что он типизированный и вам не пришлось бы приведением типов заниматься, если бы использовали его